# Why are there unconnected exposed pads on PCBs

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I've seen this in several designs. What purpose do these serve?

[image]

Comment: They're called "[fiducials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiducial_marker#Printed_Circuit_Board_.28PCB.29)".

Comment: Another option (not seen in the picture) is unmounted components. Almost any PCB is overdesigned to allow flexibility during bringup or sometimes even different products on same PCB

Comment: @GregoryKornblum he actually specifies 'unconnected', unless we are speaking of a prototyping area of the pcb usually extra components are connected to something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are [Fiducial Marks](http://www.pcb-3d.com/fiducial-marks-tutorial) and are often used for visual alignment of automated processes on PCB manufacturing and assembly.

These automated processes can vary from [pick and place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMT_placement_equipment) machines to visual inspection and [flying probes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjmjYVNuLEE).

To account for possible rotation of the board there will be at least 2 points on a PCB. In fine pitch projects there may be more fiducials near critical components. (ty [Sean](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235362/why-are-there-unconnected-exposed-pads-on-pcbs/235364#comment512412_235364) for pointing that out)

Comment: Typically there will be at least 2 per board (close to the corners), and sometimes additional ones next to fine-pitch components.

Comment: On panelized small boards the fiducials may be on the tooling strips which are subsequently removed when individual boards are depanelized from the array.